# How to communicate between threads to request next block?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, dataframe, queue

```
#Version1 
main_df = pd.read_csv('Million_rows.csv')
def myfunction(args*,start,end):
   for i in range(start,end):
    if condition1:
        for item in mainTreeSearch:
            ...
                lock.acquire()
                ###write to main_df
                lock.release()
                noLuck = False
                break
        if noLuck and Acondition:
            lock.acquire()
            ###write to main_df
            lock.release()
    elif
    ... various asymmetric decision trees...

t1 = Thread(target=myfuct, args=(args*),0,250))
t2 = Thread(target=myfuct, args=(args*),250,500))
t3 = Thread(target=myfuct, args=(args*),500,750))
t4 = Thread(target=myfuct, args=(args*),750,1000))
```

My problem is that I don't know how to feed the threads the rest of the rows, I have tried `Queue`, unsuccessfully.

```
#Version2 
def myfuntion(args*,q)
  while True:
    q.get()
    ....same search as above...without locking
    q.task_done() 

q = Queue(maxsize=0)
num_threads = 5
threads =[]
for i in range(num_threads):
   worker = Thread(target=myfunction, args=(args*))
   worker.setDaemon(True)
   threads.append(worker)
   worker.start()

for x in range(1000):
  #time.sleep(.005) 
  q.put(x)

q.join()
```

In version 2 without `sleep` either 1 thread hogs all the data or random crashes happen.

In version 1, should I use `threading.nodify()` mechanism, if so how is it implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted it to this and it works as expected

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading

q = Queue()


def myfuntion(q):
    while True:
        val = q.get()
        print('\n' + str(threading.currentThread()))
        print('\n' + str(val))
        q.task_done()


num_threads = 5
threads = []
for i in range(num_threads):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=myfuntion, args=(q,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    threads.append(worker)
    worker.start()

for x in range(1000):
    q.put(x)

q.join()
```

Check it out. I think the way you are passing the parameters is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! However, I too started with the above skeleton, queueing mechanism fails to function consistently and only adding delays seems to somewhat stabilize it. (My apologies for not being explicit, but the parameters were placeholders in this snippet and not in actual format)

Comment: Can you specify your requirements in a bit detail please?